# ASP.NET RadioButton messing with the name (groupname)

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I got a templated control (a repeater) listing some text and other markup. Each item has a radiobutton associated with it, making it possible for the user to select ONE of the items created by the repeater.

The repeater writes the radiobutton setting its id and name generated with the default ASP.NET naming convention making each radiobutton a full 'group'. This means all radiobuttons are independent on each other, which again unfortunately means I can select all radiobuttons at the same time. The radiobutton has the clever attribute 'groupname' used to set a common name, so they get grouped together and thus should be dependant (so I can only select one at a time). The problem is - this doesn't work - the repeater makes sure the id and thus the name (which controls the grouping) are different.

Since I use a repeater (could have been a listview or any other templated databound control) I can't use the RadioButtonList. So where does that leave me?

I know I've had this problem before and solved it. I know almost every ASP.NET programmer must have had it too, so why can't I google and find a solid solution to the problem? I came across solutions to enforce the grouping by JavaScript (ugly!) or even to handle the radiobuttons as non-server controls, forcing me to do a `Request.Form[name]` to read the status. I also tried experimenting with overriding the name attribute on the `PreRender` event - unfortunately the owning page and masterpage again overrides this name to reflect the full id/name, so I end up with the same wrong result.

If you have no better solution than what I posted, you are still very welcome to post your thoughts - at least I'll know that my friend 'jack' is right about how messed up ASP.NET is sometimes ;)

Comment: See: *[BUG: Radio Buttons Are Not Mutually Exclusive When Used in a Repeater Server Control](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495)*. That is just plain insane... It's a bug since 1.0 framework, and it has such a big impact. I need to inherit the radiobutton and override a couple methods to make it work (for my current ASP.NET version). What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google-fu: [asp.net radiobutton repeater problem](http://www.google.se/search?q=asp.net+radiobutton+repeater+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Indeed an unfortunate consequence of the id mangling. My take would be creating a - or picking one of the many available - custom control that adds support for same name on the client.

Answer (score 9):

**ASP.NET Tip: Using RadioButton Controls in a Repeater**

This is the code for the JavaScript function:

```
function SetUniqueRadioButton(nameregex, current)
{
   re = new RegExp(nameregex);
   for(i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
   {
      elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]
      if (elm.type == 'radio')
      {
         if (re.test(elm.name))
         {
            elm.checked = false;
         }
      }
   }
   current.checked = true;
}
```

The code is linked to the Repeater through the ItemDataBound event. For it to work properly, you need to know the name of the Repeater control, as well as the GroupName you're assigning to the RadioButtons. In this case, I'm using rptPortfolios as the name of the Repeater, and Portfolios as the group name:

```
protected void rptPortfolios_ItemDataBound(object sender,
                                           RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType
      != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      return;

   RadioButton rdo = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rdoSelected");
   string script =
      "SetUniqueRadioButton('rptPortfolios.*Portfolios',this)";
   rdo.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);

}
```

REF: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12371/

Comment: Great solution! Works very well.

Answer (score 7):

Vladimir Smirnov has already created a great custom control that resolves this issue. We have been using the [GroupRadioButton](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/How_group_RButtons.aspx) in our projects and it has been working perfectly with radio buttons created inside of a repeater and others outside the repeater all being a part of the same group.

Answer (score 6):

I use jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function norm_radio_name() {
        $("[type=radio]").each(function (i) {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var splitted = name.split("$");
            $(this).attr("name", splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        norm_radio_name();
    });

    // for UpdatePannel
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        norm_radio_name();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Beware! if you use this solution you won't be able to process user changes in the codebehind because the name/value pairs that the server is expecting will never be changed. _i.e._ anything checked/unchecked during page load will remain checked/unchecked despite user actions.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but here's what I ended up doing with a listview.  My listview is bound in VB codebehind, so I'm not sure if this will work well with a repeater, but I imagine it could be similar.

What I did was handle the OnCheckChanged event of the radiobuttons with a function that unselected any other radio buttons.  Then I looked for the selected radio button when I navigated away from the page.

This solution avoids JavaScript and jQuery, and ignores the GroupName issue completely.  It's not ideal, but it functions as (I) expected.  I hope it's helpful for others.

Markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvw" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>`
    <table>
      <th>Radio</th>
      <tr id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:RadioButton ID="rdbSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
           OnCheckedChanged="rdbSelect_Changed"/></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code:

```
Protected Sub rdbSelect_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

  Dim rb1 As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)

  For Each row As ListViewItem In lvw.Items
    Dim rb As RadioButton = row.FindControl("rdbSelect")
      If rb IsNot Nothing AndAlso rb.Checked Then
         rb.Checked = False
      End If
  Next
  rb1.Checked = True
End Sub
```

And then when the Submit button is clicked:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles btnSubmit.Click

  For Each row As ListViewItem In lvw.Items
    Dim rb As RadioButton = row.FindControl("rdbSelect")
        Dim lbl As Label
        If rb IsNot Nothing AndAlso rb.Checked = True Then
            lbl = row.FindControl("StudentID")
            Session("StudentID") = lbl.Text
        End If
    Next

    Response.Redirect("~/TransferStudent.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution! I've been looking for a solution which doesn't require javascript and never thought of just unselecting all the radiobutton `OnCheckChanged`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little better..

I have a usercontrol which is essentially a set of radiobuttons inside a repeater, each instance of the usercontrol has a public property called FilterTitle, which is unique per instance.

add these two properties to your radiobutton replacing FilterTitle with your own public property name

```
onclick='<%# "$(\"input[name$=btngroup_" + FilterTitle + "]\").removeAttr(\"checked\"); $(this).attr(\"checked\",\"checked\");" %>' GroupName='<%# "btngroup_" + FilterTitle  %>'
```

more simply..

```
onclick="$('input[name$=btngroup1]').removeAttr('checked'); $(this).attr('checked','checked');" GroupName="btngroup1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure Javascript solution for the sake of completeness.

Just add this `onclick` attribute to your `RadioButton` element(replace *GroupName* with your `RadioButton`'s GroupName):

```
<asp:RadioButton ... GroupName="GroupName" onclick="SelectRadioButton('GroupName$',this)" ... />
```

And include this Javascript in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SelectRadioButton(regexPattern, selectedRadioButton)
    {
        regex = new RegExp(regexPattern);
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
        {
            element = document.forms[0].elements[i];
            if (element.type == 'radio' && regex.test(element.name))
            {
                element.checked = false;
            }
        }
        selectedRadioButton.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Custom Control and override UniqueID to the listview UniqueID + GroupName

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MYCONTROLS
{

[ToolboxData("<{0}:MYRADIOBUTTON runat=server></{0}:MYRADIOBUTTON >")]
public class MYRADIOBUTTON : RadioButton
{
    public override string UniqueID
    {
        get
        {
            string uid = base.UniqueID;
            //Fix groupname in lisview
            if (this.Parent is ListViewDataItem && GroupName != "")
            {
                uid = this.Parent.UniqueID;
                uid = uid.Remove(uid.LastIndexOf('$'));
                uid += "$" + GroupName;

            }
            return uid;


        }
    }

}
}
```

It’s a custom control that inherits from RadioButton (public class MYRADIOBUTTON : RadioButton).
If you do nothing in the class you get a normal RadioButton. Overriding the UniqueId you can change the logic for how the name attribute is rendered.
To still keep the name unique to other controls on the page (outside the listview) you can get the UniqueId from the ListView and add GroupName to that and add it to the RadioButton.

This fix the problem with Grouping RadioButtons on different rows in a listview. You may want to add some more logic with a property to turn this feature on/off so it behaves like a normal RadioButton.

Comment: Some explanation of what your code is doing would be helpful to future readers of this answer

Comment: its the first line
Create a Custom Control and override UniqueID to the listview UniqueID + GroupName

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is bit old, but I think it might help somebody, therefore posting my solution to this issue.

This issue has 2 parts:

1. To prevent selection of more than one radio button at a time.
2. To know which radio button was clicked in server-side code.

I had the similar issue with Radio button in Repeater. I found partial solution here: 
[Simple fix for Radio Button controls in an ASP.NET Repeater using jQuery](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/87/Simple-fix-for-Radio-Button-controls-in-an-ASP-NET-Repeater-using-jQuery)

Please read the above article to get the understanding of the issue. I referred this article and it was good help. As mentioned above this issue has two parts, first is to prevent selection of more than one radio button at a time. Second, to know which radio button was clicked in server-side code. The solution posted in above article worked for me only for the first part. However code written there as well as updates to solution posted there did not work for me. So I had to modify it a bit to get it working. Here is my solution.

I wanted to create poll with Vote button. Name of my radio button (ID) is PollGroupValue with Groupname set to PollGroup in a repeater. Remember Groupname attribute in ASP.net is rendered as name attribute in generated html. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*  Step-01: */
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*  Step-02: */
    $("[name*='PollGroup']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('ci-name', $(this).attr('name'));
    });

    /*  Step-03: */
    $("[name*='PollGroup']").attr("name", $("[name*='PollGroup']").attr("name"));

    $('#Poll1_BtnVote').click(function (e) {

        /* Step - 04:  */
        if ($("[name*='PollGroup']").filter(':checked').length == 0) {
            alert('Please select an option.');
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        /* Step - 05:  */
        $("[name*='PollGroup']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('ci-name'));
        });
    });
});
```

Step 1:
Whenever a radio button is used in repeater, its groupname gets changed, since asp.net changes it so as to make it unique. Therefore each radio button gets different groupname (name attribute in client-side generated markup). Due to this, user is able to select all of the options at the same time. This issue is resolved by using jquery code as explained by subsequent comments.

Step 2:
This block of code creates a new custome attribute called ci-name and copies original value of name attribute into this new custom attribute. This process repeats for every radio button in poll. This step would help us in later step.

Step 3:
This block of code sets the value of name attributes of all radio buttons in poll to the value of name attribute of first radio button. This step prevents user from selecting more than one option at a time.

Step 4:
This code inside event handler of vote button click event, checks whether user has checked at least one option. If he hasn't, an error message is shown.

Step 5:
This code inside event handler of vote button click event, sets value of name attribute of all radio buttons to their original values. This is achieved by copying value from custom attribute ci-name. This allows asp.net server side code to know which button was actually clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I was also baffled by this bug and decided to just drop the repeater in favor of dynamically building a table with the controls inside. In your user control or on your page, simply add the following elements:

```
<asp:Table ID="theTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" Text="Column 1"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" Text="Column 2"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell runat="server" Text="Column 3"/>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Then add the data rows in the code behind with radio buttons and other required controls. You can of course do the same with other elements like the DIV:

```
<div runat="server" ID=theDiv">
</div>
```

But let us still hope for the ASP.NET team to get around to fixing this unfortunate issue with repeaters and list views. I still like the repeater control and use it whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure server side approach using reflection. The `RadioButton` control uses the `UniqueGroupName` property to determine the group name. The group name is cached inside the `_uniqueGroupName` field. By setting this field using reflection, we can override the default group name and use a group name that is the same across all radio buttons in a repeater. Please note this code must be run in the 'PreRender' event of the 'RadioButton' control to ensure the new group name is persisted across post backs.

```
protected void rbOption_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the radio button.
    RadioButton rbOption = (RadioButton) sender;

    // Set the group name.
    var groupNameField = typeof(RadioButton).GetField("_uniqueGroupName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    groupNameField.SetValue(rbOption, "MyGroupName");

    // Set the radio button to checked if it was selected at the last post back.
    var groupValue = Request.Form["MyGroupName"];

    if(rbOption.Attributes["value"] == groupValue)
    {
        rbOption.Checked = true;
    } 
}
```

`RadioButton` source code: http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/UI/WebControls/RadioButton@cs/2/RadioButton@cs

Comment: Am I correct that doing this will prevent ASP.NET from observing the `Checked` state of the RadioButton, and you'll need to manually check `Request.Form` for its state?

Comment: And it also prevents its OnCheckedChanged event handler from firing?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal solution for everyone, but I did the following using jQuery.

`<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnButton1" groupName="Group1" runat="server" />`
`<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnButton2" groupName="Group1" runat="server" />`

`etc...`

Then include the following code in your master page. (or all your pages)

```
$(function() {
//This is a workaround for Microsoft's GroupName bug.  
//Set the radio button's groupName attribute to make it work.
$('span[groupName] > input').click(function() {
    var element = this;
    var span = $(element).parent();
    if (element.checked) {
        var groupName = $(span).attr('groupName');
        var inputs = $('span[groupName=' + groupName + '] > input')
        inputs.each(function() {
            if (element != this)
                this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

A custom control/override to work around the `HtmlInputControl.RenderAttributes()` method by ignoring the `RenderedNameAttribute` property:

```
/// <summary>
/// HACK:  For Microsoft&apos;s bug whereby they mash-up value of the "name" attribute.
/// </summary>
public class NameFixHtmlInputRadioButton : HtmlInputRadioButton
{
    protected override void RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // BUG:  Usage of 'HtmlInputControl.RenderedNameAttribute'
        // writer.WriteAttribute("name", this.RenderedNameAttribute);
        writer.WriteAttribute(@"name", Attributes[@"Name"]);

        Attributes.Remove(@"name");

        var flag = false;
        var type = Type;

        if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            writer.WriteAttribute(@"type", type);
            Attributes.Remove(@"type");
            flag = true;
        }

        base.RenderAttributes(writer);

        if (flag && DesignMode)
        {
            Attributes.Add(@"type", type);
        }

        writer.Write(@" /");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used same Technic to uncheck other radio with jquery please find below code

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelectShiptoShop" runat="server" onchange="UnCheckRadio(this);" CssClass="radioShop" />
```

and script below

```
function UnCheckRadio(obj) {
           $('.radioShop input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
           $(obj).children().attr('checked', true);
       }
```