# RadioButtons, ListViews, and Grouping, oh my!

Tags: asp.net, listview, radio-button

I've got a project I'm working on where I need to put a RadioButton inside a ListView, and have them all have the same GroupName.  (can't use RadioButtonList, long story).

Anyway, this seems to be a well known bug in .NET, so I've implemented the solution found here:
[ASP.NET RadioButton messing with the name (groupname)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377393/asp-net-radiobutton-messing-with-the-name-groupname)

This works perfectly, but with one small bug which undoubtedly will come back to bite me.  If I click one radio button, and then click another while the javascript function is still running and has not completed; I can get 2 radiobuttons in the same group selected.

Any ideas?  If you need clarification; leave me a comment and I'll update my post.

**EDIT:  I believe I fixed my own issue here.  See my posted answer below.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was misguided here.

Later on in the page lifecycle; I was adding an additional onclick event that was overwriting the previous value.

In the following example:

```
var radiobutton = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton();
radiobutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test1");
radiobutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test2");
```

the onlcick attribute is set to "test2"; test1 is lost.

I ended up fixing it by appending to the existing attribute; see below:

```
radiobutton.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("{0};{1}", radiobutton.Attributes["onclick"], "My Second Script");
```

This works without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
if (!rbClicked)
    rbClicked=True;
    runJavascript();
    rbClicked=False;
```

I admit I didn't do alot of research, but this is how I've usually solved this type of problem.